# Difference between TextContent and Value of an Attribute in XML

Tags: java, xml, attributes

Is there a difference between `getTextContent()` and `getValue()` of attributes?

In the following case it prints the same into the console.
I already found out that `getNodeValue()` and `getValue` are the same (according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeValue() ).

XML:

```
<Request w="4.2">
```

Code:

```
getString("Request", rootElement);
```

and

```
void printAtt(String tagName, Element element) {
        NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = list.item(i);
            Element nodeElement = (Element) node;
            Attr attribute = nodeElement.getAttributeNode("w");
            System.out.println("ATTR NAME: " + attribute.getName());
            System.out.println("ATTR TEXT CONTENT: " + attribute.getTextContent());
            System.out.println("ATTR VALUE: " + attribute.getValue());
            System.out.println("ATTR NODE VALUE: " + attribute.getNodeValue());
        }
}
```

The output is:

```
ATTR NAME: w
ATTR TEXT CONTENT: 4.2
ATTR VALUE: 4.2
ATTR NODE VALUE: 4.2
```

Comment: There is no difference for an *attribute*, since this doesn't have any descendants, the text value of which would be included in getTextContent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a vital difference. [`getTextContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()) will concatenate all text content of its node **and** its descendants (if any) and return the value while [`getNodeValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeValue()) will return the value of its current node.

Javadoc states, `getNodeValue()`:

> The value of this node, depending on its type; see the table above.
>   When it is defined to be null, setting it has no effect, including if
>   the node is read-only.

`getTextContent()`:

> This attribute returns the text content of this node and its
>   descendants. When it is defined to be null, setting it has no effect.
>   On setting, any possible children this node may have are removed and,
>   if it the new string is not empty or null, replaced by a single Text
>   node containing the string this attribute is set to.  On getting, no
>   serialization is performed, the returned string does not contain any
>   markup. No whitespace normalization is performed and the returned
>   string does not contain the white spaces in element content (see the
>   attribute Text.isElementContentWhitespace). Similarly, on setting, no
>   parsing is performed either, the input string is taken as pure textual
>   content.  The string returned is made of the text content of this node
>   depending on its type.

For an `ATTRIBUTE_NODE`, the value of both functions are the same since an attribute has no descendant(s) hence why you are receiving similar results.

Comment: Which, however, for an attribute node collapses to being the same since an attribute node doesn't have any descendants. - I'm debating with myself whether to -1, since OP asked "...of attributes"

Comment: @laune absolutely correct. I've updated my post accordingly. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your quick and comprehensible answer!